# Padleft string using '0'

Tags: c#, .net, padleft

I have this chunk of code

```
long num = Int64.Parse(Convert.ToString(random.Next(0, 65535), 2).PadLeft(16, '0'))
```

When using this code the string is not padded with the leading zeros.  I'm not sure, but my guess is maybe when the string is parsed it removes the leading zeros from some reason?

If I do something like this

```
long num = Int64.Parse(Convert.ToString(random.Next(0, 65535), 2).PadLeft(16, '8'))
```

or any number that isn't zero, it will come out correctly to 16 digits with leading 8's.

Is there a good explanation to why this is happening?

Also is there a quick easy fix?

This is **not** a duplicate of anything using `int.ToString("D16")` or anything of that sort. I believe this is a unique problem.

Answer (score 6):

You're padding a string with `0`, then converting to an integer, so of course any leading zeros will be removed.

Ie.

```
000000123 == 123
```

While padding with `8` works, because you are creating a new number:

```
888888123 != 123
```

If you want the number padded with `0`, just remove the `Int64.Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string instead of long

```
string num = Convert.ToString(random.Next(0, 65535), 2).PadLeft(16, '0');
```

Thanks